# PHP if statement comparing variables not returning true?

Tags: php, variables

Here is my code - not sure why it isn't working:

```
<?php
$urlroot      = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$urllink      = "http://" . $urlroot;
$DirPath      = getcwd() . "\n";
$InnermostDir = basename(rtrim($DirPath, '/'));
if ($InnermostDir == $urlroot) {
    $InnermostDir = 'home';
    echo $InnermostDir;
};
?>
```

If I do an `echo` on `$InnermostDir` and `$urlroot`, they both show the domain example.com. So not sure why this won't return true?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `var_dump($InnermostDir, $urlroot);`?

Comment: `string(16) "domain.com " string(15) "domain.com"` - so it looks like I'm getting a blank space. If you can provide the solution, I'll check your answer

Comment: you sure you did the right echo? Re-add the echos and show us the output. I believe that `$InnermostDir` will show something of the absolute dir-path (from '/var/www/yourdir' or something), while urlroot comes from a URI... Not too surprising if they are different.

Comment: Why are you appending a `\n` to `$DirPath`?  Try trimming both values before comparing.

Comment: Wasn't paying attention to the \n that was the only problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$DirPath` contains a `\n` at the end, which is not removed, therefore the strings won't be equal.

`rtrim($DirPath, '/')` will only remove `/` characters from the end, not the `\n`. If you want it to remove the `\n` as well, you need to use `rtrim($DirPath, "/\n")`, or simply don't add that `\n` when setting `$DirPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Surround both variables with trim(), so:

```
<?php
$urlroot      = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$urllink      = "http://" . $urlroot;
$DirPath      = getcwd() . "\n";
$InnermostDir = basename(rtrim($DirPath, '/'));
if ( trim($InnermostDir) == trim($urlroot) ) {
    $InnermostDir = 'home';
    echo $InnermostDir;
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I put this in my /var/www dir:

```
 <?php
$urlroot      = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$urllink      = "http://" . $urlroot;
$DirPath      = getcwd() . "\n";
$InnermostDir = basename(rtrim($DirPath, '/'));
var_dump($InnermostDir);
var_dump($urlroot);
if ($InnermostDir == $urlroot) {
    $InnermostDir = 'home';
    echo $InnermostDir;
};
?>
```

And call it with localhost/test.php I get

> string(4) "www " string(9) "localhost"

which would fail the `if`?